# SDcard filename as datestamp

Tags: stm32, sd-card

I'm using STM32F072RB nucleo board and I have interfaced SDcard breatkout board with it. 
I'm able to Read / Write a text file and I am also using RTC. Project is more of a datalogger.
I have interfaced LM35 with STM32 analog pin and I'm able to log the data with the timestamp.

The next thing I'm trying is to have the filename, like "MAY09_00.TXT". To get the filename as mentioned above, I have to read the RTC date and Time and then put it into filename. The problem is that when I read date(which is in uint8_t) and cast it to (char) it takes up the ASCII char value and not the date as char. It seems like a classic problem, and I did try to look up online but couldnt found much help. I know that I'm looking for function like itoa() but those are really for Standard C library. I'm not aware if ST provides such utility library for their MCU.

```
char *fname;
char filename[12] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','_','0','0','.','T','X','T'};

HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &time3, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
  HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &date, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);  

  if(date.Month == 1)
  {
    fname = "JAN ";
  }
  else if(date.Month == 2)
  {
    fname = "FEB ";
  }
  else if(date.Month == 3)
  {
    fname = "MAR ";
  }
  else if(date.Month == 4)
  {
    fname = "APR ";
  }
  else if(date.Month == 5)
  {
    fname = "MAY ";
  }

  if(date.Date < 60)
  {
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    int len = 0;
    for(i=0; *(fname) != NULL; i++)
    {
      filename[i] = *(fname);
      if(*(fname)==' ')
      {
        filename[i] = '0';
      }
      fname++;
    }
    filename[4] = (date.Date); // when I use today's date 9, it takes /t instead of '9'
  }
```

Comment: solved it. used to logic to convert single digit decimal to ascii char. First do {num &= 0x0F} then do {num |= 0x30} and then cast to { (char) num }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full logic. Following logic is for two digit date.

```
dt = date.Date;
dt = (dt % 10);
dt &= 0x0f;
dt |= 0x30;
filename[3] = (char) dt;

dt2 = date.Date;
dt2 = (dt2 / 10);
dt2 &= 0x0f;
dt2 |= 0x30;
filename[4] = (char) dt2;
```